# How do I create a list from a single string without splitting the string in python

Tags: list, python-2.7

Hi I have a dynamic string and I want to create a list with the string in it.

```
Ex. a = "hello"
    b = xxx(a) should give ['hello']

when I try
    b = list(a), I get b = ['h','e','l','l','o']
```

How do I achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a list with a single element instead:

```
b = [a]
```

Comment: Hitting myself on the head. Thanks a lot